# Rails Bootstrap tabs. Dropzone in tabs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, dropzone.js

I dynamically create bootstrap tabs and each tab has a `partial`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs-from-locales" role="tablist">

  <% @locales.each_with_index do |locale, i| %>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link <%= 'active' if i == 0 %>"
           id="<%= locale.downcase %>-locale-tab"
           data-toggle="tab" href="#<%= locale.downcase %>"
           role="tab"
           aria-controls="<%= locale.downcase %>"
           aria-selected="true"><%= locale %></a>
      </li>

  <% end %>

</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="tabs-from-locales-content">

  <%= @locales.each_with_index do |locale, i| %>
      <div
      class="tab-pane fade <%= 'show active' if i == 0 %>"
      id="<%= locale.downcase %>"
      role="tabpanel"
      aria-labelledby="<%= locale.downcase %>-tab"> A + <%= i %> <%= render 'form' %> </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

The partial is a `form` that has another partial with the `dropzone` div.

```
<%= form_with(:id => 'my-form', model: [:admin, @island], local: true, 

    html: {id: 'myForm'}) do |f| %>

       ....
       ....

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= render partial: 'shared/dropzone', locals: {upload_url: admin_pictures_path, thumbnail_urls: @thumbnail_urls} %>
        </div>

        <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

    <% end %>
```

The `dropzone` partial includes the dropzone setup.

Dropzone works normally on the first tab, although at the other tabs it doesn't seem to get initialized and the `fallback` div is visible.

I have a `js` file that initialized and configures my `dropzone` setup.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function () {
    if (document.getElementById('picture_dropzone')) {
        console.log("element found.")
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        // noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
        var pictureDropzone = new Dropzone('div#picture_dropzone', {

        ....
        ....
     }
```

Any ideas why `dropzone` fails to initialize at the other tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the ID `#picture_dropzone` to search for the all the `dropzone` elements. Of course, you can only have one element have a certain ID; the other elements with that ID will be ignored. That's why only the first `dropzone` is being initialized and not the rest.

If you add a class (`.picture_dropzone`) to your `dropzone` divs, then you can search that and the search will return all of the `dropzone` divs and not just the first one.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? A code snippet would be nice. I am doing `$(".dropzone").each(function (i, index) {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var pictureDropzone = new Dropzone('div#'+ this.id, { ...} ` this now, but unofrtunately i am getting an error `Dropzone is already attached`

Comment: Are the IDs of the dropzone divs unique? Your new code snippet looks good except for the `new Dropzone('div#'+ this.id, { ...}` part. If the IDs are all the same, then it will try to initialize the first dropzone div over and over again.